Saving a new custom editor document with a custom extension
I'm creating a ChatGPT "editor" in VS Code where you can have a chat window open not unlike the one OpenAI created for ChatGPT. I don't have any problems with creating the editor or saving and loading documents per se, but if I create a new document and then save it the save dialog defaults the file type to json and not the extension I created for the file - the extension I created isn't even in the save as type dropdown. It is json behind the scenes, but I don't want it to automatically save as json. I don't want to manually register a type in VS Code, instead I want this to all link up and work from having the extension installed and enabled.

My goal is that when I create a new gpt document and try to save it (e.g. create new document and immediately press Ctrl+S) that the save dialog box will recognize this as a "gpt" document instead of a "json" document.
I tried configuring the customEditors section of the package.json file as it is in the supplied sample:
    "customEditors": [
      {
        "viewType": "sfcodegpt.chat",
        "displayName": "GPT",
        "selector": [
          {
            "filenamePattern": "*.gpt"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

That didn't work
I tried adding in a languages tag to extend it to *.gpt:
  "languages": [
    {
      "id": "json",
      "extensions": [
        ".gpt"
      ],
      "aliases": [
        "Chat GPT Book"
      ]
    }
  ]

That didn't work.
I don't know how to make this work and looking at documentation, samples, and googling I can't find anything on this specific thing. I don't even know if I need to code something/update my CustomTextEditorProvider dervied class or if it's config somewhere.

I needed to add a files.associations to the package.json:
  "files.associations": {
      "*.gpt": "gpt"
  }

This isn't in the documentation for the package.json file: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest
But it seems to merge your package.json into the vscode settings, makes sense.
Anyway, hopefully, this helps someone else.
